# SQL How to get avg per day

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have a table that looks like this:

| Train | Date | Passengers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 100 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 50 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 | 25 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | 90 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 30 |
| 3 | 2020-01-02 | 40 |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | 80 |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | 20 |
| 3 | 2020-01-03 | 60 |

I need to get average per day, but because dates are same per 3 rows in ***Date*** with this code:

```
SELECT Date, Train, avg(Passengers) AS Avg_Passengers
FROM trainstation
WHERE Date != Date + 1 -- I know it's wrong like this but I don't know how to make a condition like this
group by Date, Train
```

I get an error and without the ***WHERE*** I get same table but in float type the number of passengers

Result that I want:

| Date | Avg_Passengers |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 58.333 |
| 2020-01-02 | 46.666 |
| 2020-01-03 | 53.333 |

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff just edited

Comment: . . .That is the second query in my answer.  I figured you wanted something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the average passengers *per train*, you would use:

```
SELECT Train, avg(Passengers) AS Avg_Passengers
FROM trainstation
GROUP BY Train;
```

If you want the average across all trains per day:

```
SELECT Date, avg(Passengers) AS Avg_Passengers
FROM trainstation
GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: Purely speculation, but perhaps it's because the answer was provided before the question was edited - rather nullifying your own suggestion that the question be improved; and a form of gatekeeping, if you will

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  from
   (
    select Date, Train, sum(passenger) as 'price'
    from table
    group by Date, Train
   )
group by Date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you :

```
select Datepart(day, Date), avg(passengers)
    from yourTable
    group by Datepart(day, Date)
```